# Exploiting symmetry in Armadillo

Tags: c++, rcpp, armadillo

Is there any way to exploit the fact that the resulting matrix in Armadillo is symmetric? I often have products of the form `A * B * A.t()` (where `B` is symmetric and positive definite) and I wonder if there is some way to do the multiplication faster by using this fact. I've made some simple attempts, but they are either equally as fast or substantially slower. It would be interesting to see a function which provides a speed improvement (or explains why it isn't possible to obtain one).

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat m1(const arma::mat & A, const arma::mat & B) {
  arma::mat C = (A * B) * A.t();
  return C;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat m2(const arma::mat & A, const arma::mat & B) {
  arma::mat C1 = (A * B);
  arma::mat C2 = arma::mat(arma::size(C1), arma::fill::zeros);
  arma::uword n = C1.n_rows;

  for (arma::uword i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (arma::uword j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
      C2(i, j) = arma::as_scalar(C1.row(i) * A.row(j).t());
    }
  }
  C2 = arma::symmatl(C2);
  return C2;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat m3(const arma::mat & A, const arma::mat & B) {
  arma::mat C1 = (A * B);
  arma::mat C2 = arma::mat(arma::size(C1), arma::fill::zeros);
  arma::uword n = C1.n_rows;

  for (arma::uword i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (arma::uword j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
      C2.submat(i, j, i, j) = C1.row(i) * A.row(j).t();
    }
  }
  C2 = arma::symmatl(C2);
  return C2;
}

/*** R
n <- 10
A <- matrix(rnorm(n*n), n, n)
B <- crossprod(matrix(rnorm(n*n), n, n))


microbenchmark::microbenchmark(m1(A, B), m2(A, B), m3(A, B))

all.equal(m1(A, B), m2(A, B))
all.equal(m1(A, B), m3(A, B))
*/
```

Comment: When I search for "symmetric" at http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.htmlI get 61 hits. That doesn't imply that every operation you could do on matrices is supported.  There is cost in providing interfaces, making sure LAPACK is available etc pp.  You can always tune some more...

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Sure, and by no means was I complaining that this is not implemented at the moment. I'm mostly just curious to see if there is a way, given the current infrastructure, to write a function that can use the symmetry in an efficient way. For a very general library this kind of tuning probably does not make sense, but given that I do this kind of multiplication over and over in my case I think it's worthwhile looking into.

Comment: Back when I was young the elders did not have fancy libraries such as Armadillo but homespun C or Fortran code doing ABA^t and other "common" ops in a hand-optimised.  This is generally hard as compilers and cpus have different preferences.  But yes: if _you_ do this a lot then _you_ may have a reason to tune this. I am still not sure we can expect Conrad to optimised all those cases.